# Python : How to filter multiple conditions

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I'm trying to filter multiple conditions, but every attempt I do is in vain.

I want to filter every string (ex. Apple, Banana, stage, books etc), but the code just doesn't work as I expected.

```
B = []

wanted_type1 = 'A'
unwanted_type2 = {'Apple','Banana','Orange','Melon'}
unwanted_type3 = {'stage','books','films','music'}

al = urllib.request.urlopen(URL).read()
als = json.loads(al)
a_list = als['response']['results']
for list in a_list:
    if (a_list['type1'] == 'A') and (a_list['type2'] != unwanted_type2) and (a_list['typeb'] != unwanted_type3):
       B.append(list['type4'])
```

The first condition, "  a_list['type1'] == 'A'  " was fine.

But the others, "  a_list['type2'] != unwanted_type2  " and "  a_list['typeb'] != unwanted_type3  " are not working at all. They are not filtering any conditions that I've included in unwanted_type2 and unwanted_type3.

But if I included only one condition, like

```
if (a_list['type1'] == 'A') and (a_list['type2'] != 'Apple') and (a_list['typeb'] != 'stage'):
```

then it worked.

What am I doing wrong....?

Comment: Your code is not a complete example, so I can only guess. You are probably comparing strings to sets and always get `False`.

Comment: use `filter` function on the list, while making a function that returns True or False depending on your conditions.

Comment: So `a_list['type2']` seems to be a string, `'Apple'` for example. Why should that string ever be equal to the set `{'Apple','Banana','Orange','Melon'}`?

Comment: @timgeb The code before this line is way too long, so I thought posting the whole code would be useless. I guess by 'sets' you are referring to unwanted_type2 and type 3?

Comment: You are not supposed to post your whole code, but construct a small example that mimics your code. In this specific case, hardcoding the `a_list` datastructure such that we can copy and paste your code for debugging purposes would have done the trick. Yes, `unwanted_type2` and `unwanted_type3` are sets.

Comment: Oh.... As a_list['type2'] has so many strings like Apple, Banana, Strawberry, Pineapple etc, I wanted to filter them.

Comment: Again, you can show the problem with a small `a_list`.

Comment: @timgeb I've updated the example code and included "    al = urllib.request.urlopen(URL).read()
    als = json.loads(al)" before a_list

Comment: Sorry this does not improve the question. The code still cannot be run by others. You can just type in something for `a_list`. But the problem should be solved by Khaos' answer in any case.

Comment: @timgebI know you tried to help, but I don't even know how to ask a  'good' question.... As you can clearly see, I am so new to python and don't know what I'm doing wrong. But thank you for trying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic behind the code is wrong.

If you do `a_list['type2'] != unwanted_type2` is like `a_list['type2'] !={'Apple','Banana','Orange','Melon'}`, and you are comparing a value to the entire unwated_type2.

To resolve it, you can use `not in` in the condition:

```
B = []

wanted_type1 = 'A'
unwanted_type2 = {'Apple','Banana','Orange','Melon'}
unwanted_type3 = {'stage','books','films','music'}

a_list = some_variable['response']['results']
for list in a_list:
    if (a_list['type1'] == 'A') and (a_list['type2'] not in unwanted_type2) and (a_list['typeb'] not in unwanted_type3):
       B.append(list['type4'])
```

With this method you are looking at

Comment: I tried this code and it clearly produces the filtered result I wanted ! I don't know how to thank you enough !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are comparing "string" and list(or iterable)

Try changing code to something below:

```py
unwanted_type2 = ['Apple','Banana','Orange','Melon']

if "Apple" in unwanted_type2:
    print("Condition works!")

if "Raspberry" not in unwanted_type2:
    print("Negative condition works!")
```